# Assembly x86 outputting incremented value

Tags: ubuntu, assembly, x86, cpu-architecture

I'm terribly new to Assembly, and I've been stuck at what I initially considered an easy thing to do. 
I need to input two values, one smaller than the other, and output all the numbers in between.
For example, 1 and 4, output: 
1
2
3
4

Now I've managed to input the numbers, and I've managed to output first two digits, but only manually. I can't understand how to use a loop and what conditions to look at.
I'm sure I have to compare the two values, and increment the first until it's equal to the second, but I'm uncertain of how it's done.

This is my code:

```
lequal:
# output first number
movl valore, %eax
addl $-48,%eax
call itoa 

inc %eax #increment value of valore?
loop lequal
jmp end
```

I am guessing perhaps:

```
movl valore, %eax
addl $-48,%eax
movl valore2,%ebx
addl $-48,%ebx
cmp %eax, %ebx
```

comparing both values is needed in order to know when to stop incrementing the value of first integer?

I only get the first integer outputted, endlessly, because I used a loop, and the incrementation is simply overlooked, for some reason.

Anyway, I'd appreciate any help provided. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should read online guidance on how X86 instructions work. If you do that and study examples, I think you will figure this out. For example, the `loop` instruction is a good construct for loops, but it uses the `ecx` register as the loop counter per documentation (e.g., see http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Control_Flow). I don't see where you set `ecx` in your code. Also, there is a `subl` instruction, so you could say `subl $48,%eax` instead of `addl $-48,%eax` if you wish.

Comment: If you're learing assembly and are new to it, you should try implementing these kind of things in C/C++ first, then look at the disassembly.

Comment: And IMO, you should try another assembler with better syntax. GAS is not for humans. It is aimed for source code, generated by compilers. For humans, FASM or even NASM is way better.